# How to enable MySQLi extension in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

How to enable MySQLi extension for PHP in htaccess? Is it even possible to enable PHP extensions through htaccess file?

Comment: Please provide some more context to allow others to give relevant answers and rate answers accordingly. Are you on a shared hosting server? Do you have (shell) access to the server?

Answer (score 1):

***You don't.***

**Mysqli should be installed as a PHP-module and loaded through `php.ini`.**

Assuming you use a debian-related Linux distribution, this can be done by issuing `apt-get install php5-mysqli`.

If this is not an option, please read the PHP documentation on this module and follow the steps described there.

Answer (score 1):

The extension= directive is only valid in the central `php.ini`, it cannot be set from within .htaccess files.

At best you could load it manually in your PHP script:

```
<?php
   dl("mysqli.so");
```

Only works until PHP 5.2

Comment: and how does one fix this after 5.2?

Comment: Like mentioned, per `php.ini`. Better yet, by [not using mysql_*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) anymore.